# Tests for ray-sphere intersection

Tags: unit-testing, testing, raytracing

I am implementing ray tracing and faced the strange problem: the spheres sometimes look like ellipses. I don't know why, but I suppose the problem is in the geometry, so I want to unit test the code (ray intersection with different figures). Where can I find good tests for this problem? I thought of some myself, but they are working, and I can't find the problem.

The picture is related.

[image: Ray Tracing bug]

Comment: Can You post some pictures? The thing You are describing can be caused by some camera setup/mechanics going wrong (e.g aspect ratio or/and FOV). You can test it actually tracing the spheres with a orthographic camera.

Comment: Seems like FOV thing. And I doubt there is anything that can be done with it other then setting it to 75 deg or less. It is a common thing to happen with pin-hole cameras and wide FOV. You can notice the thing also happening in any game when You set up FOV to values over 90 (in FPS online shooters for instance).